# Чтение логов, которые постоянно пополняются

Tags: java, файлы

Есть файл логов, который постоянно пополняется логами. 
Размер файла может достигнуть несколько сотен мегабайт.
Не хочется каждый раз считывать файл полностью, так как это много времени занимает.
Нужно сделать механизм считывания данных таким образом, чтобы в отдельном потоке крутился считыватель, и я бы мог в любое время получить актуальные логи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Tailer implements Runnable {
    private File file;
    private int runEvery;
    private long lastPosition = 0;
    private boolean run = true;

    public Tailer(String inputFile, int interval) {
        file = new File(inputFile);
        this.runEvery = interval;
    }

    public void stop() {
        run = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(run) {
                Thread.sleep(runEvery);
                long fileLength = file.length();
                if(fileLength > lastPosition) { 
                    RandomAccessFile fh = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
                    fh.seek(lastPosition);

                    byte c;
                    while((c = (byte)fh.read()) != -1) {
                        System.out.print((char)c);
                    }
                    lastPosition = fh.getFilePointer();
                    fh.close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            stop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        Tailer tailer = new Tailer("test.log", 1000);
        executor.execute(tailer);
    } 
}
```

Comment: уже лучше )), это больше нравится

Comment: Значит можно отметить как решение ;)

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, что вам нужен Stream, с получением позиции. Вы можете применить на стриме метод .skip() и пропустить первые байты, которые вы уже вывели из файла. Набросал простенький класс

```
class Worker
{
    Logger logger = new Logger();
    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        //Запускаем логгер в отдельном потоке
        Thread logThread = new Thread(logger);
        logThread.start();

        //Какая то работа
        //
        //
        //

//Остановить логгер
        logger.flag = false;
    }
}

//Класс логгера, имплементируем Runnable, чтобы получить возможность запускать логгер в отдельном потоке
class Logger implements Runnable
{
//Текущая позиция в нашем файле
    private long currentPosition;
    private FileInputStream fis = null;
    private BufferedReader reader = null;
//Используем, чтобы остановить логгнр
    public boolean flag = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        fis = new FileInputStream("C:/sample.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        while(flag) {
            try {
                //Можно вызывать reader.skip(currentPosition);, чтобы пропустить прочитанные байты
                String line = reader.readLine();
                WriteLog(line);

                //Записываем текущую позицию потока, можем использовать позицию где угодно, развивая наш логгер
                currentPosition = fis.getChannel().position();
                //Симулируем логгинг каждую секунду
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void WriteLog(String message)
    {
        //Здесь выводите сообщение куда угодно, например 
        System.out.printf(message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я реализовал. Singleton класс

```
package main.java.services;

import main.java.utils.*;

import javax.imageio.stream.*;
import java.io.*;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class LogFileService{

    private static boolean running = true;
    private static File fileName;
    private static BufferedInputStream reader;
    private static StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    private static LogFileService instance = null;


    public LogFileService() throws FileNotFoundException {
        fileName = new File("C:\\log.log");
        reader   = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream( fileName ) );
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        this.instance = this;
    }


    private void run() {
        while( running ) {

            try {
                if( reader.available() > 0 ) {
                    stringBuilder.append( (char)reader.read() );
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        sleep( 500 );
                    }
                    catch( InterruptedException ex ) {}
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void start(){
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            LogFileService.getInstance().run();
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static LogFileService getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            try {
                instance = new LogFileService();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Messages.getInstance().error(fileName.getAbsolutePath() + " not found", e);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static StringBuilder getLog(){
        return stringBuilder;
    }

}
```